# Getting cateogry id from custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I've created a custom post type and abled the creation of categories within it. But I'm having problem getting category ID's from said custom post type. These are the functions I've used to create the custom post type:

http://pastebin.com/aAtsKHx4

Tried var_dumping get_categories(), get_taxonomies() How can I get the ID's of the categories?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this ([wp_get_post_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms))

```
//Returns Array of Term ID's for "category"
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category', array("fields" => "ids"));
```